# Subversion: How to organize svn tags for Visual Studio solutions -- or -- How to version an entire VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, svn, solution

I have the following directories in my Subversion repository for a Visual Studio solution:

- ProjectName

  - tags
  - branches
  - trunk

    - MySolution.sln
    - MyProject1 (dir)
    - MyProject2 (dir)

If I update **MyProject1** from version **1.0.0** to **2.0.0**, should I copy everything in **trunk** to a new directory under **tags**, or should I only copy everything in **trunk/MyProject1** to a new directory under **tags**?

And, if the former is the correct way of doing things, how do I version an entire Visual Studio solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [svn guide](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to understand basic versioning concepts.

**Trunk** is the main line of development so you can update from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1, 2.0.0 etc.

**Branch** is a copy of your trunk to develop a feature or something else without affecting the Trunk. You can merge at any time the branch code to the trunk code or throw it away.

**Tag** is a snapshot at a given time of your trunk o branch.

In your case you can update from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 in trunk and maybe keep a snapshot by tagging your 1.0.0.0 release (copying all trunk to a tag named 1.0.0.0).

First you can checkout ProjectName to your local disk, for example c:\working\ProjectName.
In this way you have this first local structure:

- ProjectName

  - tags
  - branches
  - trunk

    - MySolution.sln
    - MyProject1 (dir)
    - MyProject2 (dir)

When you reach your 1.0.0.0 release tag it to have this structure:

- ProjectName

  - tags

    - 1.0.0.0

      - MySolution.sln
      - MyProject1 (dir)
      - MyProject2 (dir)
  - branches
  - trunk

    - MySolution.sln
    - MyProject1 (dir)
    - MyProject2 (dir)

Then update to 2.0.0.0 and so on:

- ProjectName

  - tags

    - 1.0.0.0

      - MySolution.sln
      - MyProject1 (dir)
      - MyProject2 (dir)
    - 2.0.0.0

      - MySolution.sln
      - MyProject1 (dir)
      - MyProject2 (dir)
  - branches
  - trunk

    - MySolution.sln
    - MyProject1 (dir)
    - MyProject2 (dir)

At any time you can work on trunk or release 1 or 2 (maybe for debugging or applying patches)

Comment: This is the answer I thought I'd get. So, I should include MyProject2 in the tag even though it didn't change at all.

Comment: You have to think at your solution as a whole. So you tag entire solution not only MyProject2.
And don't worry, it's not a space waste because a tag is only a "reference" to a particular revision. No code is duplicated.

Comment: What I find a little troubling about that method is that the tag-naming scheme becomes arbitrary. I know the version of a live MyProject2 dll because the version number is embedded in the assembly. But I have no easy way of correlating that assembly version with an svn tag because the svn tag version is arbitrary and has no correlation with the assembly version. Oh well...

Comment: Ok, this is a different problem and require more than 500 character of a comment :-)
You're right, it's very important to keep in sync assembly version with svn revision (SVN Revision is the sequential number incremented at each commit).
This problem has different solution (from easiest to complex).
1 - in a small dev team you can get next SVN revision number and modify AssemblyVersion before committing.
2 - you can use MSBuildTask to automate above process
3 - you can add a Continuous Server to your software lifecycle to tag automatically your SVN revision